# passing function name to execute as parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm using a $.ajax function that serves two purposes and depending on the context, I want to execute different functions on the call-back.

```
function MyAjaxCall(SomeParameter, CallBackFunctionName) {

  $.ajax({
   ...
   success: function (msg) {

     var TheData = msg.hasOwnProperty("d") ? msg['d'] : msg;
     // here: "execute the function in parameter CallBackFunctionName 
     // AND pass it the parameter TheData
  }
}
```

How do I write the line where the name of the function is a parameter and I want to pass it TheData as the parameter.

Note, at the moment, I'm writing it like that:

```
if (CallBackFunctionName === "SomeFunctionName1") {
   SomeFunctionName1(TheData);
} else {
   SomeFunctionName2(TheData);
}
```

Comment: is that function a global function? why don't you just pass the actual function into the MyAjaxCall method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the function is defined as a global function then use :

```
window[functionName](arguments);
```

If it isn't then change the way `MyAjaxCall` is called like so:

```
MyAjaxCall.apply(thisArg, [SomeParameter, CallBackFunction]); //thisArg is the value of the this object inside MyAjaxCall().
```

Then inside `MyAjaxCall()` do this:

```
function MyAjaxXall(SomeParam, CallBackFunction){
  var me = this; //the object supplied through thisArg while calling.
  $.ajax({
     success : function(msg)
     {
         //whatever processing you want
         me[CallBackFunction](arguments);
     }

  });
}
```

Or you could add the object as part of the paramters of `MyAjaxCall()`:

```
function MyAjaxCall(SomeParam, obj, CallBackFunction)
{

      $.ajax({
         success : function(msg)
         {
             //whatever processing you want
             obj[CallBackFunction](arguments);
         }

      });
}
```

When using it for calling a global function use:

```
MyAjaxCall(SomeParam, window, CallBackFunction);
```

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer. Upvoted because of the concept but I'm keeping my implementation because it's simpler. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the defined function which name is passed via the variable CallBackFunctionName is global, you could do this:

```
window[CallBackFunctionName](TheData)
```

You could also just pass the actual function to `MyAjaxCall` like this:

```
var MyCallbackFunction = function(data){ console.log(data) }
MyAjaxCall({param1: 'value1'}, MyCallbackFunction)
```

This way you can just execute the function:

```
function MyAjaxCall(SomeParameter, CallBackFunction) {

  $.ajax({
   ...
   success: function (msg) {

     var TheData = msg.hasOwnProperty("d") ? msg['d'] : msg;
     CallBackFunction(TheData)
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's all inside a closure and none of these functions are accessible from the global scope.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer. Upvoted because of the concept but I'm keeping my implementation because it's simpler. Thanks again.